# Laravel authentication - Auth vs Sentry

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I started using [Sentry](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry) for authentication on my first project.

Now I want to know if my choice to use Sentry is good or not.

Which one is better? [Laravel's Auth](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security) or Sentry.

Does it exists alternative libraries better than above two that I can use in my project built with laravel?

Comment: It depends on your requirement Laravel's Auth is a simple authentication where as Sentry provides more functionality like Groups, Throttle etc..

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy and convenient to use built-in authentication in Laravel(4). You have access to current user object which is also an instance of Eloquent ORM Model.

```
$currentUser = Auth::user();
```

Then managing users accounts and roles is very easy and intuitive. For reference http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

Answer (score 0):

Sentry is fine for authentication, and it much more feature packed than Laravel's default auth.

If you are a paying customer of Cartalyst, Sentintel is the newer version of Sentry and is very good.

Also, you can look at confide and entrust packages that provide similar functionality.